# How to escape string </script> in a verbatim string literal inside <script runat="server">

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `ASP.NET 4.0 Web forms`. I want to escape `</script>` tag in script tag defined on an aspx page. Code as simple as this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Theme="" %>
<script runat="server">
    string dfd = @"<script></script>";
</script>
```

is simply not working. How can I tell the compiler not to count it as server-side script closing tag?

Please help!

Comment: this has got nothing to do with the compiler.... but rather your code. what exactly are you trying to achieve? you have a script tag (runat server) then another script tag being declared in a string variable....what are you planning on doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just break the `string` and concat using the [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) method, for sample:

```
string dfd = string.Concat("<script>", "</", "script>";
```

Or if you need to add some code, for sample:

```
string dfd = string.Concat("<script>", "alert('Hello World!');", "</", "script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string dfd = @"<script><//script>";
```

You have to escape the slash.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
string dfd = "&lt;script&gt;...Code...&lt;\/script&gt";
```

i found this, [here](http://www.herongyang.com/JavaScript/Browser-Use-HTML-Entity-to-Protect-HTML-Tag.html)